# what is the correct term for this

Tags: electric-guitar

I play guitar in a musical group.

What is the correct musical term when all instruments including drums would play/strum a particular note with some force? I have been using the term "syncopation" incorrectly because I did not know the correct term to use.

Comment: Did you mean "when **all** instruments..." or "...a note **with some force**"?

Comment: A “hit” or a “stab” what your looking for? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stab_(music)

Comment: If the accent comes in an unusual place in the bar, then it will still be a 'syncopation' - so it could be a 'syncopated stab/hit'.

Comment: thank u everyone for your comments.  After all i was using the term "syncopation" correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If it’s a little more force, an ***accent***. If it has a lot of attack you could say it’s ***marcato***. Although, if you want something a little less classical you could call it a “hit”.

Comment: **Unison** ('one sound') means you all play the same note or notes, without harmony. **Tutti** ('all') means you ALL play, though not necessarily in unison. Yer average band wouldn't normally use either of these words though.

Comment: You could also say unison accent or tutti accent, I think.

Answer (score 1):

'Sfortzando' is a word that works. I don't think there's a special term for *everyone* playing thus simultaneously, but on a score - yes, even for a small group - those notes would be marked as ***sf***.